# Авторизация, куки

Tags: php, cookie, авторизация

Доброго времени суток. Возникла проблема следующего содержания:

Есть файл авторизации, авторизация происходит по кукам. В случае верных данных, авторизация успешна, но если перейти на другую страницу, то авторизация пропадает. Сам файл авторизации включен во все страницы. Прошу помочь, у кого какие есть идеи, как это исправить?

Код файла:

```
class UserAuth {
    var $_db=null;
    var $userid=null;
    var $username=null;
    var $usercookie=null;
    var $sessioncookie=null;
    var $session_id=null;
    function UserAuth(&$db) {
        $this->_db =& $db;

    }
    function Login($user,$pass){
        if (!$user || !$pass) {
          return FALSE;
        }

        $this->_db->setQuery( "SELECT * "
            . "\nFROM user "
            . "\nWHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass' and status='active'"
        );
        $row = null;
        if (!$this->_db->loadObject( $row )) {
          return FALSE;
        }

        if (defined( '_ACL_ADMIN' )) {
            if ($row->vip!='1') return FALSE;
        }
        $lifetime = time() + 365*24*60*60;
        setcookie( "usercookie[username]", $user, $lifetime, "/" );
        setcookie( "usercookie[id]", $row->id, $lifetime, "/" );
        $this->initSession();

        $this->_db->setQuery( "update session "
            . "\n set "
            . "\n  userid='$row->id',"
            . "\n  sess_start=now(),"
            . "\n  sess_expire=DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL ".(_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)." MINUTE),"
            . "\n  last_activity=now(),"
            . "\n  ip='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',"
            . "\n  user_agent='".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
            . "' where  session='$this->session_id'"
        );
        $this->_db->query();
        $this->userid=$row->id;
        $this->username=$user;
        $this->usercookie['username']=$user;
        $this->usercookie['id']=$row->id;
        return TRUE;

    }
    function Logout(){
        if ($this->Check_Auth()) {
            $this->_db->setQuery( "delete from session  where  session='$this->session_id'");
            $this->_db->query();

        }
        setcookie( "usercookie[username]", "", time() - 36000, "/" );
        setcookie( "usercookie[id]", "", time() - 36000, "/" );
        setcookie( "sessioncookie", "", time() - 36000, "/" );

    }
    function generateId() {
        $failsafe = 20;
        $randnum = 0;
        while ($failsafe--) {
            $randnum = md5( uniqid( microtime(), 1 ) );
            if ($randnum != "") {
                $cryptrandnum = md5( $randnum );
                $this->_db->setQuery( "SELECT * FROM session WHERE session=MD5('$randnum')" );
                if(!$result = $this->_db->query()) {
                    die( $this->_db->stderr( true ));
                    // todo: handle gracefully
                }
                if ($this->_db->getNumRows($result) == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        $this->sessioncookie = $randnum;
        $this->session_id = md5( $randnum . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
    }

    function initSession() {

        $sessioncookie = GetParam( $_COOKIE, 'sessioncookie', null );
        $sess=md5( $sessioncookie . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );

        $row = null;
        $this->_db->setQuery("select * from session where session='$sess'");

        if ($this->_db->loadObject( $row )) {
            // Session cookie exists, update time in session table
            $this->_db->setQuery("update session set last_activity=now(), ".
                "sess_expire=DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL ".(_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)." MINUTE) where session='$sess'");
            $this->_db->query();
            $this->sessioncookie=$sessioncookie;
            $this->session_id=$row->session;
        } else {
            $this->generateId();
            setcookie( "sessioncookie", $this->sessioncookie, time() + 43200, "/" );
            $this->_db->setQuery("insert into session set last_activity=now(), session='$this->session_id',".
                "sess_expire=DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL ".(_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)." MINUTE)  ");
            $this->_db->query();

        }
    }
    function Check_Auth(){
        $sess = GetParam( $_COOKIE, 'sessioncookie', null );
        $ucookie = GetParam( $_COOKIE, 'usercookie', null );
        $sess=md5( $sess . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );

        $this->_db->setQuery("delete from session where now()>sess_expire"); //PURGE SESSION
        $this->_db->query();

        $row = null;
        $this->_db->setQuery("select * from session a left join user b
            on a.userid=b.id where session='$sess'");

        if (!$this->_db->loadObject( $row )) {
           return FALSE;
        }
        if (($row->id==$ucookie['id'])&&($row->username==$ucookie['username'])
            &&($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']==$row->ip)){
            //authenticated ok
          if (defined( '_ACL_ADMIN' )) {
                if ($row->vip!='1') return FALSE;
          }
          $this->userid=$row->id;
          $this->username=$row->username;
          $this->usercookie['username']=$row->username;
          $this->usercookie['id']=$row->id;
          $this->sessioncookie = GetParam( $_COOKIE, 'sessioncookie', null );
          $this->session_id = $sess;
          if (!defined(_TIMEOUT_ABSOLUTE)){
                $this->_db->setQuery("update session set last_activity=now(), ".
                    "sess_expire=DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL ".(_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)." MINUTE) where session='$sess'");
                $this->_db->query();

          }else{
                $this->_db->setQuery("update session set last_activity=now()  where session='$sess'");
                $this->_db->query();
          }
           return TRUE;
        }else{
           return FALSE;
        }
    }
}

function GetParam( &$arr, $name, $def=null ) {
    $return = null;
    if (isset( $arr[$name] )) {
        return $arr[$name];
    } else {
        return $def;
    }

}
```

На другой странице проверяю авторизацию:

```
 $auth= new UserAuth($sql);
 if(!$auth->Check_Auth())
     {
       echo "Не авторизован";
     }   else {
                echo "Добро пожаловать".$auth->username."<br />";
              }
```

Но желаемого эффекта получить не могу...

Comment: посмотрел базу, обнаружил что у меня прикаждой авторизации, новая сессия вбита, может причина в этом, что при открытии новой страницы, какждый раз меняется сессия...

Comment: не видно из примеров где и как вы стартуете сессию

Answer (score 1):

Очень вероятно, что у вас вообще не устанавливаются куки. Это может произойти в случае если **до** session_start/setcookie произошел какой-то вывод:

- `echo` или
- вывод `предупреждения` PHP или
- символы `BOM` перед `<?php`.

Для начала надо в самом браузере посмотреть на куки. Они есть? Они фиксированы для одного юзера + сеанса работы или всякий раз разные?

Другой вероятный вариант: у вас уже есть куки **с тем же именем**, но относящиеся к родительскому домену или другой папке. В итоге читаются они, а не те которые вы ставите. Надо почистить всё перед тестированием.

Answer (score 0):

То, что в базе плодятся сессии авторизации - это нормально. Причину вы изложили правильно, на всех последующих страницах сессия не запускается и приходится снова проходить авторизацию. Попробуйте в начало файла, для которого нужен авторизованный доступ, всписать:

```
session_start ();
```

Comment: у меня есть файл, в котором запускаются все классы и функции, этот файл я вставляю в каждую страницу. 

и инициализация сессии в нем я прописал...

        session_name('sessionid');
        session_start();

Comment: Ну вы позаглядывайте в куки браузера: реально sessionid фиксируется или на каждой странице новое значение? А может быть вообще отсутствует (из-за "header already sent")

Answer (score 0):

var_dump($_COOKIE) в начале каждой страницы.
var_dump($_SESSION) в начале каждой страницы.

дальше действовать по обстоятельствам. Если все нужны переменные попадают в $_SESSION - ищите ошибку в коде, который с сессией работает. Если в сессии нет нужных данных - ищите ошибку в способе отправки куков и тп вещах.
Да, посмотрите настройки в php.ini, касающиеся cookies и session (прямо так по файлу и поищите). Я точно не помню, какие они там бывают, но точно есть какие-то ограничения.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start();`  и подключить на все страницы.

Я так решил эту проблему.

Только Сессии (как и другие куки) следует отправлять до любого вывода текста (до DOCTYPE).